# Not receiving jenkins email artifact

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, build-automation, email-notifications

I am trying to email the apk from Jenkins once build is succeeded. In the post action of the jenkins job I have selected editable email notification and mentioned the file path in the attachment. Below is the last few lines of console log:

[SignApksBuilder] signed APK TestProject/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
[SignApksBuilder] archiving signed APK TestProject/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
[SignApksBuilder] finished signing APKs

Email was triggered for: Success

Sending email for trigger: Success

Sending email to: name@domain.in

Finished: SUCCESS

But I didn't receive any mail. Test configuration using email notification, I'm getting the mail. Not sure why I'm not getting mail with editable email notification. Please help me in figuring out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Check if the test email is coming for you. If not, there is some problem with the Email configuration that you have done in Jenkins > manage > configure a system.

Comment: @Vighnesh Pai  path mentioned in the attachment is wrong. After changing the path I'm receiving email. Thanks for your reply.